# how to convert a text into HTML text in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, tooltip

In my angular app, I need to push to a value into an array where the value type should be of type HTML.
The displayed value should render as an HTML text. 
Say for example when I hover over the text, I need to display an HTML table as a tooltip.
array.push(' HOVER THIS TEXT TO SEE HTML Table');

Comment: please share code which you have tried to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your HTML to [innerHTML] like this:

```
<span [innerHTML]="yourHtmlAsAString"></span>
```